# Connecting to SQL server through a script and automatically generate data and sent to user as an email

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, email, automation

I am working on one concept to reduce the routine work where we query to generate data and sent to client. Can this be possible?

My total query:-

Is there a possibility like to use a script that connects to SQL server and executes a query to generate data and send the data to the user in the form of email with the file attached preferably an .XLS or .XLSX or .csv format.

But the user who is running the script is not having any sql related installed on his machine.

Can someone advise me.

Thank you.

Best regards

Comment: Typically, if you don't even know what language you're working in yet, you need to do more research on Google before posting to Stack Overflow. But I'll be nice this time and provide an answer.

Comment: the script could be either VB or Java Script.

Comment: I am querying for a solution of this sort. Please see below link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely with Sql Server, as an agent job.

If you need this for some reason to run on the end-user's own machine, you can do it via a Powershell script or vbscript that you call from a Scheduled Task. You will need the Sql Server Native Client installed on the machine for this to work, but if that user does anything at all that talks to the database (like use an database driven application) then they likely already have this.

Comment: Joel Thank you. is there any other possibility that without having any client installed on the end users machine. Is there any possibility like we are having a script that connects to SQL server, authentication done, executing the query on the server, generating data, and sending the generated data as an xls file to the end user as an email

Comment: @Vinod You need the Sql Server Native client, which unfortunately did not ship with Windows. Beyond that, you'll need to rely on an smtp server somewhere to send the e-mail.

Comment: Can you guide me how to proceed. or can you suggest me what can be done to reduce the routine work here

Comment: i have done some research link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301799.aspx . Instead of Outlook i am searching for a solution to user a script.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is almost similar to the *Joel Coehoorn* gave you. Also you can find a PowerShell script for emailing in my [blog article](http://myqaengineering.blogspot.com/2014/04/custom-continuous-integration-testing.html). As far as I understand you want to automate it all.

Of course you'll have to modify it a little bit, to fit your needs. But the logic is there. If you still have some questions about it, please just ask.

*UPDATE*

I don't see why not. But since I'm familiar with PowerShell, I'll suggest you the similar solution as [described in this article](http://irisclasson.com/2013/10/16/how-do-i-query-a-sql-server-db-using-powershell-and-how-do-i-filter-format-and-output-to-a-file-stupid-question-251-255/). Pseudo code for sample workflow:

```
SqlClient.SqlConnection -->
$command.CommandText = $query -->
| Out-File C:\..\result.txt -->
send-mailmessage -Attachments "C:\..\result.txt"
```

According to **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245198.aspx)** the **sqlcmd** script supports more complex logic than Transact-SQL scripts. About emailing part - [look here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx). Please note that you'll most probable need the **[SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)** server details from your admins.